# Search all files and in all files

Tags: linux, macos

I'm looking one script, tool ... for linux that it find all files and in all files the key word, similar at OSX Finder (I'm not looking one app with the same Finder interface, but only same works)

e.g. if i search in OSX Finder "linux" I get :

```
linux (directory with linux name)
linux-2.4.0 (directory with linux in name)
...
memory.h (file with linux in text)
...
command.c (file with linux in text)
...
so-08-filesystem.pdf (pdf with linux in text)
...
```

Is there anything like this for linux?

Thanks to everyone, but use "find" and "grep" (in all their variants), look for files and in files seen as linux files, i.e. as their characters encoding is stored in memory. It will not work for example with .pdf files

Answer (score 1):

yes, no need to download anything, just open the terminal up and do:

`sudo find / -name "*keyword*"`

and this will search your base dir (/) for any files that match the keyword. The stars mean anything can be on either side of the keyword.. e.g. if I did:

`sudo find / -name "*.html"`

it will return:

```
/var/www/index.html
/var/www/list.html
```

Answer (score 0):

find command is used to find all files from a directory in recursive order and can execute more scripts with find command for finding content from those files.

```
find sourcedirectory/ -iname "*file*" -exec grep -i keyword {} \;
```

This above command will find all files from sourcedirectory which have names file in either side of file name.and then grep command used to search keyword variable from those files.

if want to search from all files in a directory then use below command.

```
find sourcedirectory/ -type f -exec grep -i keyword {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own finder. Add the following function to ~/.bashrc file

```
finder() {
    find -name "*$1*" && grep -r "$1"
}
```